# How can I make a single PyQt code to work in Windows and Linux?

Tags: pyqt

[PyQt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt) experts: I developed the GUI in Windows and used `setGeometry` to position the widgets. When I tried to run the same code in Linux it looks cluttered.

And added to that in Windows the font size of 8 seems good. But in Linux, especially in Ubuntu, it doesn't appear well since the font size is 10 by default. Some among the differences are the border of the group box doesn't appear in Linux while it is visible in Windows..

Is there a way that I can make the same code to get the same look and feel in Windows and Linux irrespective of the font and size changes and other differences?

In future if I port my application to Mac will the same code work there too? Or should I have to maintain the separate code for each by checking with `platform.system()` equal to "windows" or "linux"?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: don't use setGeometry directly (to position your widgets).

Consider the following: what if the user wants to resize your application window?

Compose the user interface (you could do this from Designer or from code) within QSplitters (if you want a resize handle between two components) and/or within QVBoxLayouts / QHBoxLayouts (note that these can be nested).

This will make your UI components behave consistently.

Comment: Thanks christo for your reply.. But we can't have the spacing between the widgets as desired.. In some areas I've had to use overlapped borders to achieve the desired effects.. Even if we set the spacing to 0 we cant achieve customisation to that much.. Is there any other way of doing that??

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ChristopheD. Using setGeometry is bad. It's like designing a webpage with fixed pixel geometry and then wondering why it looks bad on another device.

Qt has a lot of wonderful layout code. Let it do it's job.

Qt by default will paint a widget according to instructions contained in the QStyle. You can test how badly you break your layout in different styles easily enough... run your program with different style options. Like so:
    program.py -style motif
Also try `-style platinum` or `-style windows`. Even different versions of Windows will probably break your layout.

If you really want to see how bad pixel-based layouts are, try running your program with the -reverse parameter... that's how your program will look to someone running it who speaks a Right-To-Left language, like Hebrew or Farsi.

The problem that you have with widgets not drawing where you want them to can be solved by creating custom painting code for your widget. See the [PyQt QPainter docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qpainter.html) or better yet, the original [Qt QPainter docs.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html).

While I hope my answer is useful, it probably means your program needs to be partially rewritten. In the long term, however, it means that you'll have code that is portable between styles and operating systems, and will even work translated (assuming you care about that).